# dynamically generate div tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am modifying a website template to suit my needs, and to do that, I need to dynamically generate `div` tags, each of a different ID. I am using PHP to connect to my database.

```
<?php do { ?>
    //dynamically generated div tags
<?php } while ($row_all_courses = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_courses)); ?>
```

I followed Marc B's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084994/dynamically-generate-divs-with-different-ids-with-php), but as there is much data between `<div>` and `</div>` tags, I can't do it in a single echo statement.
Any ideas how to do it will be very helpful, thanks :)

I am posting my whole code, which is sort of temporary but can give some idea what I want to do :

```
<?php do { ?>
  <?php echo  "<div class='section section_with_padding'     id=".$row_courses['c_id']."'>"; ?>
    <h1><?php echo $row_courses['c_name']?></h1> 
    <div class="half left">
      <p><em><?php echo $row_courses['description']?></em></p>
    </div>
    <div class="half right">
      <div class="img_border img_nom">
      <a href="#gallery"><img src="images/templatemo_image_01.jpg" alt="image 1" /></a> 
    </div>
    <a href="#home" class="home_btn">home</a> 
    <?php echo "<a href='#".$row_courses['c_id']."' class='page_nav_btn     previous'>Previous</a>" ?>
    <a href="#gallery" class="page_nav_btn next">Next</a> 
  </div> <!-- END of Services -->
<?php } while ($row_courses = mysql_fetch_assoc($courses)); ?>
```

Comment: Is your `$row_courses['c_id']` a number? Because css id's that start with or are just numbers are invalid.

Comment: yes DickieBoy is right you cant use number for id use something like id="course-<?php echo $row_courses['c_id']; ?>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php do { ?>
  <div id ="my_div_<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <?php //whatever you want in here ?>
  </div>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php } while ($row_all_courses = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_courses)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cant echo it in one statement, echo it in 2?

```
echo "<div>";
//your stuff will be printed here
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

just echo id in php and leave everything else to be HTML .

so this is easier :

```
<?php do { ?>
    ...
    <div id="<?php echo "number".$id ?>">
     my content
    </div>
    ...
<?php } while ($row_courses = mysql_fetch_assoc($courses)); ?>
```

This way's advantage is that you can modify or debug Your HTML code very easier than echoing everything in php.

Comment: thing is that, the content in every div will very as I am pulling the data to show from database

Comment: Im saying separate html and php for your ease, dont echo html with php.

Comment: just echo the texts and numbers with php, **within** html,

Comment: Css id's that start with or are just numbers are invalid.

Comment: I am using dreamweaver and when I tried to do `<div id="<?php echo $id ?>">`, It showed that as error, so I was confused.

Comment: @tigerden Thats probably because you don't have a `$id` variable

Comment: define a dynamic `$id` like : `$id="number".$id;$id++;`

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row_all_courses = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_courses)){

echo '<div id="'.$row_courses['c_id'].'">';

//do stuff....

echo '</div>';


}
```

Comment: Css id's that start with or are just numbers are invalid.

Comment: Okay @DickieBoy, Then I will use some other parameter like c_name as ID, is it okay?

Comment: perfectly ok. DickieBoy is right. I was showing you the path ;)